# App crashes on first-time launch only in Sony devices

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

We are using Worklight JSONStore in a native Android application.

Whenever we are installing the app for the first time, the app is crashes - it will not crash after opening it for the second time.

We were able to find the logs and find that the problem is in sqlite (JSONStore).
We have added the logs below.

```
01-20 10:03:27.682: W/ActivityThread(23197): Application com.MeaWallet can be debugged on port 8100...
01-20 10:03:27.802: D/webcoreglue(23197): netstack: Memory Cache feature is ON
01-20 10:03:28.002: D/JSENGINE(23197): qualcomm.jsengine.version:C.2-patch35-git:7b7ad6f
01-20 10:03:28.022: I/TAG(23197): **************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/cache DELETED *******************
01-20 10:03:28.022: I/TAG(23197): **************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/files DELETED *******************
01-20 10:03:28.022: I/TAG(23197): **************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/app___WL_EVENTS DELETED *******************
01-20 10:03:28.032: I/TAG(23197): **************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/databases DELETED *******************
01-20 10:03:28.032: I/TAG(23197): **************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/shared_prefs DELETED *******************
01-20 10:03:28.032: E/SQLiteLog(23197): (1802) os_unix.c:30033: (2) stat(/data/data/com.MeaWallet/databases/webview.db) - 
01-20 10:03:28.032: E/SQLiteLog(23197): (1802) statement aborts at 9: [CREATE TABLE formurl (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, url TEXT);] 
01-20 10:03:28.032: E/SQLiteLog(23197): (1) statement aborts at 2: [ROLLBACK;] cannot rollback - no transaction is active
01-20 10:03:28.032: W/dalvikvm(23197): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415b68b0)
01-20 10:03:28.082: E/AndroidRuntime(23197): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9715
01-20 10:03:28.082: E/AndroidRuntime(23197): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: cannot rollback - no transaction is active (code 1)
01-20 10:03:28.082: E/AndroidRuntime(23197):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(Native Method)
01-20 10:03:28.082: E/AndroidRuntime(23197):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:555)
01-20 10:03:28.082: E/AndroidRuntime(23197):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:439)
01-20 10:03:28.082: E/AndroidRuntime(23197):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:401)
01-20 10:03:28.082: E/AndroidRuntime(23197):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:530)
01-20 10:03:28.082: E/AndroidRuntime(23197):    at android.webkit.WebViewDatabaseClassic.initDatabase(WebViewDatabaseClassic.java:165)
01-20 10:03:28.082: E/AndroidRuntime(23197):    at android.webkit.WebViewDatabaseClassic.init(WebViewDatabaseClassic.java:130)
01-20 10:03:28.082: E/AndroidRuntime(23197):    at android.webkit.WebViewDatabaseClassic.access$000(WebViewDatabaseClassic.java:35)
01-20 10:03:28.082: E/AndroidRuntime(23197):    at android.webkit.WebViewDatabaseClassic$1.run(WebViewDatabaseClassic.java:109)
01-20 10:03:28.092: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(23197): Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException in Logger.java:400 :: Uncaught Exception
01-20 10:03:28.092: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(23197): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: cannot rollback - no transaction is active (code 1)
01-20 10:03:28.092: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(23197):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(Native Method)
01-20 10:03:28.092: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(23197):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:555)
01-20 10:03:28.092: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(23197):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:439)
01-20 10:03:28.092: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(23197):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:401)
01-20 10:03:28.092: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(23197):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:530)
01-20 10:03:28.092: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(23197):  at android.webkit.WebViewDatabaseClassic.initDatabase(WebViewDatabaseClassic.java:165)
01-20 10:03:28.092: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(23197):  at android.webkit.WebViewDatabaseClassic.init(WebViewDatabaseClassic.java:130)
01-20 10:03:28.092: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(23197):  at android.webkit.WebViewDatabaseClassic.access$000(WebViewDatabaseClassic.java:35)
01-20 10:03:28.092: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(23197):  at android.webkit.WebViewDatabaseClassic$1.run(WebViewDatabaseClassic.java:109)
01-20 10:03:28.112: D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils(23197): WLUtils.loadLib in WLUtils.java:533 :: Extracting zip file: featurelibs/armeabi/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
01-20 10:03:28.152: D/HostStatisticManager(23197): netstack: DNS Host Prioritization is: ON, Version: 5.0.1
01-20 10:03:28.152: I/(23197): netstack: LIB_MGR - Lib loaded: libdnshostprio.so
01-20 10:03:28.152: I/(23197): netstack: STAT_HUB - Succeeded to load plugin: libdnshostprio.so
01-20 10:03:28.152: E/(23197): netstack: LIB_MGR - Error loading lib spl_proc_plugin.so
01-20 10:03:28.152: E/(23197): netstack: STAT_HUB - Failed to load plugin: spl_proc_plugin.so
01-20 10:03:28.152: I/(23197): netstack: LIB_MGR - Lib loaded: pp_proc_plugin.so
01-20 10:03:28.152: I/(23197): netstack: STAT_HUB - Succeeded to load plugin: pp_proc_plugin.so
01-20 10:03:28.152: E/(23197): netstack:  STAT_HUB - App com.MeaWallet isn't supported
01-20 10:03:28.273: D/dalvikvm(23197): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.MeaWallet/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 0x4185f6a8
01-20 10:03:28.273: D/dalvikvm(23197): Added shared lib /data/data/com.MeaWallet/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 0x4185f6a8
01-20 10:03:28.273: D/dalvikvm(23197): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.MeaWallet/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 0x4185f6a8, skipping init
01-20 10:03:28.273: D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils(23197): WLUtils.loadLib in WLUtils.java:541 :: Loading library using System.load: /data/data/com.MeaWallet/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
01-20 10:03:28.303: D/dalvikvm(23197): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.MeaWallet-1/libstlport_shared.so 0x4185f6a8
01-20 10:03:28.303: D/dalvikvm(23197): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.MeaWallet-1/libstlport_shared.so 0x4185f6a8
01-20 10:03:28.303: D/dalvikvm(23197): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.MeaWallet-1/libstlport_shared.so 0x4185f6a8, skipping init
01-20 10:03:28.303: D/dalvikvm(23197): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.MeaWallet-1/libsqlcipher_android.so 0x4185f6a8
01-20 10:03:28.303: D/dalvikvm(23197): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.MeaWallet-1/libsqlcipher_android.so 0x4185f6a8
01-20 10:03:28.303: D/dalvikvm(23197): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.MeaWallet-1/libsqlcipher_android.so 0x4185f6a8, skipping init
01-20 10:03:28.303: D/dalvikvm(23197): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.MeaWallet-1/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so 0x4185f6a8
01-20 10:03:28.303: D/dalvikvm(23197): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.MeaWallet-1/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so 0x4185f6a8
01-20 10:03:28.303: I/Database(23197): JNI_OnLoad called
01-20 10:03:28.303: I/Database(23197): JNI_OnLoad register methods 
01-20 10:03:29.334: D/JSONSTORE(23197): JSONStoreLogger.logDebug in JSONStoreLogger.java:174 :: provisioning database "user" (already exists: false)
01-20 10:03:29.394: D/JSONSTORE(23197): JSONStoreLogger.logDebug in JSONStoreLogger.java:174 :: provisioning database "mktMsg" (already exists: false)
01-20 10:03:29.454: D/JSONSTORE(23197): JSONStoreLogger.logDebug in JSONStoreLogger.java:174 :: provisioning database "simplytapp" (already exists: false)
01-20 10:03:31.126: D/JSONSTORE(23197): JSONStoreLogger.logDebug in JSONStoreLogger.java:174 :: provisioning database "event" (already exists: false)
01-20 10:03:31.186: D/JSONSTORE(23197): JSONStoreLogger.logDebug in JSONStoreLogger.java:174 :: provisioning database "widget" (already exists: false)
01-20 10:03:31.256: D/JSONSTORE(23197): JSONStoreLogger.logDebug in JSONStoreLogger.java:174 :: provisioning database "receiptList" (already exists: false)
01-20 10:03:31.316: V/DeviceInfoManager(23197): DeviceInfo is: {"device_properties":[{"data":{"product":"C5303","device":"C5303","model":"C5303","hardware":"qcom","manufacturer":"Sony"},"available":true,"name":"device"},{"data":{"version":"18","name":"Android"},"available":true,"name":"os"},{"available":true,"name":"camera"},{"available":false,"name":"hce"},{"data":{"mac_address":"44:d4:e0:3c:d9:36"},"available":true,"name":"wifi"},{"available":false,"name":"credenSE"}]}
01-20 10:03:31.366: W/HomeActivity(23197): HomeActivity.java DESTROYED!
01-20 10:03:31.376: D/WLClient(23197): WLClient.createInstance in WLClient.java:169 :: WLClient has already been created.
01-20 10:03:31.406: W/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush(23197): WLPush.unregisterReceivers in WLPush.java:763 :: unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush$3@41c11b40
01-20 10:03:31.406: V/WalletServerManager(23197): Set challenge handler to MwChallengeHandler
01-20 10:03:31.406: W/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush(23197): WLPush.unregisterReceivers in WLPush.java:768 :: unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush$4@41c11df8
01-20 10:03:31.426: W/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush(23197): WLPush.unregisterReceivers in WLPush.java:773 :: unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush$5@41c120b0
```

Relevant code snippet (from comments below):

```
List<JSONStoreCollection> collections = new ArrayList<JSONStoreCollection>(); 
uRDao = new UserInfoDao(); 
JSONStoreCollection userStore = userDao.getJsonStoreCollection(); 
collections.add(userStore); 
MMDao = new MarketMessageDao(); 
JSONStoreCollection MMStore = MMDao.getJsonStoreCollection();
collections.add(marketMessageStore); 
WLJSONStore.getInstance(application).openCollections(collections);
```

The code fails somewhere on the initialization.

```
public class EventDao extends BaseDao<EventPojo> {

    public EventDao() {
        super(EventPojo.class);
    }

    @Override
    public JSONStoreCollection getJsonStoreCollection() {
        try {
            store = new JSONStoreCollection("event");
        } catch (JSONStoreInvalidSchemaException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception " + Util.printException(e));
            return null;
        }

        return store;
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Worklight are you using?

Comment: Can you include your code and what you are trying to do? Does it work on other devices/emulators?

Comment: we have used Worklight 6.2  .

Comment: @DanielA.González Code cannot be included , ya it works fine on other devices except on sony xperia.

Comment: @RahulHawge, does it work on other, non-Sony, devices? Does it crash in any Android OS version or specific version?

Comment: @RahulHawge, please provide the exact device model and OS version.

Comment: yes it works fine on other non-sony devices. All sony xperia and non sony xperia devices are using android 4.4 which we use for testing.

Comment: sony Xperia  GO and sony xperia z series , android os version 4.4

Comment: What exact version of 6.2 are you on? Also, I don't want you to include all your code, just the code snippets relevant to JSONStore causing the failure, if you have determined that.

Comment: we are using worklight 6.2.0.01-20141027-1531.

Comment: Have you stepped through that code? Does it die in the openCollections method, or any of the previous methods?

Comment: we couldnt find where it is failing, all we got is the logs which we have attached. The failing is happening as soon as we install the app. Please go throught the logs and try to give some suggestion.\

Comment: The only thing the logs tell me is that SQLLite fails rolling back a transaction. I have no way of knowing if this happens on the openCollections method of JSONStore, or one of your DAO objects. I also have no way of knowing if the correct collections are being passed, which is why your help is needed in narrowing this down.

Comment: If this is not possible, then please open a PMR so that IBM support can further help you.

Comment: Also try to create a minimized version of your app (perhaps even a NEW app with just dummy data require for the JSONStore initialization that reproduces the error). Without reproduction further assistance cannot be provided.

Comment: @DanielA.González Thanks for the suggestion.But i guess it is failing in openCollections method.

Comment: @IdanAdar i think this issues is from worklight side, do you have suggestion for this issue.

Comment: Balajig, if you want s confirmation of a bug then you need to provide an application that reproduces the error so that it could be debugged first. Provide an application.

Comment: As @DanielA.González has said if you cannot reveal the definition of your DAO class then you can try opening a PMR to help you. There might something going on that interfering with the transaction processes in SQL.

Comment: Its probabily failing at the openCollectionStore() and the i am also adding the definition of dao file.

Comment: Balajig, exactly what Daniel and nafmo told you.

Comment: Namfo asked, i have added the dao definition in this question . \

Comment: @IdanAdar Ok, as i worklight Hybrid app, how to provide the password in android Native code while using JSON Store. How to make the JSONStore  while using in android to encrypt the data and store as we do in hybrid by adding usePassword?

Comment: What does that has to do with the crash? Do you want to solve the crash or not? if this is a different question - open another question.

Comment: @IdanAdar Nobody is answer the question , by going through the logs given i found out that the crash is associated with encryption of the key. SO i wanted to remove the encryption if given in the android code. SO i asked the question. I am trying to understand from the logs how it is happening thats all.My question is releavant to the question.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you. Open a PMR and provide the full app so *it could be debugged*.

Comment: @IdanAdar , what is PMR , and how to do it.

Comment: If you are an IBM customer, you can open a support ticket (PMR). Contact your IBM contact person.

Comment: @BalajiG, Any updates? did you open a PMR? Is this still happening? Did you find a solution?

Comment: @IdanAdar yeah did little bit of code changes by adding checks in jsonStores creation. And it stopped crashing.

Comment: @BalajiG or Rahul, can you please provide the answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

BalajiG and Rahul Hawge are not responding the comments. 
This was solved by them like so:

> yeah did little bit of code changes by adding checks in jsonStores
>   creation. And it stopped crashing.